# Laravel 5 and NodeJS

Tags: php, node.js, laravel

I am battling with myself about the use of Laravel 5 AND / OR NodeJS.
I want to build a webshop where other webshops or stores can sell their products on. NodeJS drops in when a visitor is viewing an auction page and a product has a new bid. It should be visible without refreshing the (product)page. The rest of the website won't need this functionality.
So, 2 backend environments are awkward, right? So should I pick NodeJS, Laravel 5 or should I just use both for this page only?

Comment: This is primarily opion-based: "Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about Laravel which is a PHP framework but whatever you want to achieve can be achieved using node js with [socket io](http://socket.io/) support. You can have realtime updates using socket io. Please check it out. No need to have two frameworks of different language platforms to achieve a single task. And it is wrong to compare socket io(event based communication engine) to Laravel (php web application framwork).

Comment: But node js is a backend technology right? So when I use socket io ain't I using 2 backend technologies anyway?

Answer (score 1):

You can use both of them. their architecture and nature is different. Laravel is a **framework** with php language that **runs per request** but node.js is a **platform** that is best suitable for streaming and realtime. If you want a CMS like website then I suggest Laravel because Development cost and maitenance is better, due to its active community. If you developed that with Laravel, then you can use push notifications to inform your users from new changes or you can use methods like long pulling.